# How do I modify private final String variable?

Tags: java

```
public class x {
    private final String a;

    public void x() {
        a = "Hi";
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

`private final String a;` <- this line is showing error that 'a' is not initialized.

I tried `private final String a = ""`;

And `a = "Hi"`;

Then it says I cannot assign a value to final variable.

How do I modify or assign new value to final String in another method?

Comment: You can't. That's the point of a final variable.

Comment: A final variable cannot be modified. If you want to modify it, remove the final keyword.

Comment: There is a possibility using reflection, but it is definitively a bad idea, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection if you are really interested in this. But again, IT IS A BAD IDEA.

Comment: You can assign a value in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You have an unwanted keyword "void" in there such that what you think is your constructor is actually a function definition.  Just remove the `void` and all will be well:

```
public class x {
    private final String a;

    public x() {
        a = "Hi";
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

As you see, you can set a `final` variable in a constructor if you didn't give it a value when you defined it.

You talk about modifying `a` in another method.  You can't do that, as others have pointed out in the comments.  That's the whole point of `final`. It declares that the value of `a` will be set once and will never change once set.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a final value, so if you want to add "Hi" as a string to that final string you should initialize it like: `private final String a = "Hi";`

or if you want to modify it later you have to remove final.

Answer (score 0):

For the final static variable, it is compulsory that you should perform initialization before class loading completion. You can initialize a final static variable at the time of declaration or inside the static block.

```
class Test {
    final static int x = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

OR in static block.

```
class Test {
    final static int x;
    static
    {
        x = 10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```